# Are the derivatives of the same functions always the same?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, derivatives

Suppose we have define function $k:$

$$k(x):=h\circ g^{-1}(x)$$

If $g^{-1}:x \rightarrow y$ such that $g^{-1}(x)=y$, it seems plausible that $k(x)= h(y)$. However, is it true that $$\frac{d^2h(y)}{d^2y}=\frac{d^2k(x)}{d^2x}?$$

---

On the one hand I think that $\frac{d^2(h\circ g^{-1}(x))}{d^2(x)} \neq \frac{d^2h(y)}{d^2y}$. However, if $k(x)= h(y)$, it's hard to see how the second derivatives may be different.

Comment: Per chain rule, $k'(g(y))\cdot g'(y) = h'(y)$

Comment: How would it even be possible for one and the same function to have two different derivatives?